# Use SAS Macro Variable within Proc SQL Teradata passthrough

Tags: sql, sas

I have a SQL statement that I wish to automate using SAS EG (9.4).  The following statement has been tested in Teradata SQL Assistant and works.

```
select * from TD.DATA where date='2015-06-01'
```

Now I wish to push this through a proc SQL pass through, and feed the date to the SQL program, like so....

```
proc sql;
connect to teradata as tera(user=&tera_user password="&tera_pwd" tdpid=terap);
create table MYDATA as 
select * from connection to tera
(
select * from TD.DATA where date='2015-06-01'
);
disconnect from tera;
quit;
```

The above code has been tested and produces the exact same output as the previous SQL statement.  However, what I really want is to do something like this:

```
%let input_date='2015-06-01';
proc sql;
connect to teradata as tera(user=&tera_user password="&tera_pwd" tdpid=terap);
create table MYDATA as 
select * from connection to tera
(
select * from TD.DATA where date=&input_date.
);
disconnect from tera;
quit;
```

I have tried various combinations of quotations and different date formats....what am I missing here?  Thanks.

Comment: Try using `%STR(')` instead of just a single-quote

Comment: Strange - that code you provide looks fine to me (with the single quotes being assigned inside the macro variable).  I tested it against a mySQL database and it worked fine.  Can you try it one more time just to humor me because I find it difficult to believe that it isn't working.  Maybe do it in a new SAS session.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `%BQUOTE()` macro function to resolve macro variables within single quotes.

```
%let input_date = 2015-06-01;
proc sql;
  connect to teradata as tera(user=&tera_user password="&tera_pwd" tdpid=terap);
  create table MYDATA as 
  select * from connection to tera
  (
   select * from TD.DATA where date = %BQUOTE('&INPUT_DATE')
  );
  disconnect from tera;
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks, Chris!  This solution is perfect, and I learned a new macro function.

Comment: I am getting "Teradata prepare: A character string failed conversion to a numeric value". Any ideas?

Comment: @csetzkorn Does the string represent a valid date?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
%let input_date=2015-06-01;
proc sql;
connect to teradata as tera(user=&tera_user password="&tera_pwd" tdpid=terap);
create table MYDATA as 
select * from connection to tera
(
select * from TD.DATA where date=%str(%'&input_date%')
);
disconnect from tera;
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks, Stig.  This works perfectly, though I prefer Chris J's solution.  It looks a little cleaner.

Comment: Hi, yeah the BQUOTE looked better, Im going to use that in the future too ;)

Answer (score 0):

as with such format of date 201501 to make a working macrovariable

```
%let input_date = 201506;
%let input_date2=input(put(intnx('month',%sysfunc(inputn(&input_date,yymmn6.)),0,'b'),10.),yymmddd10.)
proc sql;
  connect to teradata as tera(user=&tera_user password="&tera_pwd" tdpid=terap);
  create table MYDATA as 
  select * from connection to tera
  (
   select * from TD.DATA where date = %BQUOTE('&INPUT_DATE2')
  );
  disconnect from tera;
quit;
```

Comment: Can you explain? What is the supposed effect of `%BQUOTE('&INPUT_DATE2')`?

Comment: just as input_date=2015-06-01